# How to implement JDBC Driver 8.4 to connect MS SQL Server using Google Sheets

Tags: sql-server, performance, jdbc, google-sheets

I have managed to connect to my MS SQL Server database via google sheet script, using https://github.com/ebarreat/Google-Spreadsheet-JDBC.

I did a simple query to select all the 2k rows from a table of 30 columns, but it is very slow.  I thought I would bring my SQL Server JDBC driver up-to-date first and then search for some performance improvements.

Using the getDriverName() of the metadata, gives "Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0", whereas the latest release is 8.4.

I have installed the latest version on my SQL Server computer, but don't know how to make it available to my Google Sheets script.  Articles on the web suggest that I should add the driver's bin folder path to the classpath and the Windows path. I defined both and rebooted the computer but I still get the same result for getDriverName(). I am not a java person but understand the code. Can someone please help?

U:>echo %path%
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;...

U:>echo %classpath%
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

I am using SQL Server 2016 on Windows 10.

I can provide the script I am using but it is exactly a copy of the gitHub.

Also, I would appreciate any lead to improve performance.

Many thanks.

Comment: Google sheets doesn't run on your server, so having the driver on your SQL Server system makes no sense, the driver needs to be where Google Sheets runs, but I'm not sure if you can actually replace the driver it already has. Your performance problem is likely due to latency between your SQL Server system and the Google datacenter where your sheet is running.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply. I understand that Google Sheets does not run on my SQL Server Computer but what I don't know is how I can update the JDBC driver on the SQL Server or how I can get the newly installed one is used by SQL Server.  Indeed, any idea where the getDriverName() gets the information from? or as you suggested can it be replaced?

Comment: The JDBC driver is used by Google Sheets, likely Google includes their own version. You can't update _"the JDBC driver on the SQL Server"_, because your SQL Server doesn't have nor use a JDBC driver.

Comment: @Mark Many thanks for your reply. The reason for trying to update the driver was that I saw an article saying adding 'sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false' to the JDBC connection string may improve performance, but when I did, the script failed with "unsupported property". I thought perhaps the new version of the JDBC driver supports this property. Maybe that solution does not apply to google sheet scripts but to java apps. This is the first time I have attempted connecting to SQL Server server over the net; still learning.